# Additional Code File for Windows Forms Form

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Can I add another code file to a Windows Forms Form so that it appears below the form in the Solution Explorer?

- MyWindow.cv

  - MyWindow.designer.cs
  - MyWindow.cs
  - **MyWindow.Helpers.cs**

If I just add another file with this name, it isn't files below MyWindow. Moreover, it is displayed with a Form icon. My code file has grown huge, that is why I'd like to split it up.

Cheers
Matthias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution would be to extract helper classes.
But you can simply add a new class file (not a new windows forms file) and save your project. Open the csproj file in a text editor and locate the `<Compile Include="yourNewFile.cs">` tag of the newly added file.
Inside this tag, add a new tag `<DependentUpon>YourParent.cs</DependentUpon>`, where `YourParent.cs` is the file you want to put the new file under. Save the csproj file and switch back to VS and reload the project file.

Comment: Does this work in Visual Studio 2010? I cannot do this: "Cannot move 'MyWindow.Helpers.cs'. The destination folder is the same as the source folder."

Comment: Yep, thanks. VS now opens the file in designer mode by default, but I can live well with explicitly choosing "View Code".

Comment: Try adding a `<SubType>Code</SubType>` tag to directly after the `DependentUpon` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Although there isn't a way to do that, you could add the two form (and associated code files) into a **folder**, which in essence, achieves the same effect.

I'd also like to mention that under "good class design", you'd refractor and separate your code out so that it is more easily maintainable and easier to follow. You may have heard of these, but principles like "separation of concerns", "DRY" and "unit of work" really make a difference if and when your application becomes fat and gains another 1,000,000 lines of code.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have heard of them. But I'm struggling, as the code contains merely event handlers. There are, however, like thirty buttons on a ribbon as well as some binding sources and input controls, and I don't know (technically) how to divide things into pieces properly...

Comment: @Mudu, although my posts are subjective, and I might be completely wrong here, why would you have more than 20 items on your screen? Perhaps some of the controls could be associated with each other, and added into some kind of visual control (basically a class for UI objects).

Comment: In general, I fully agree with you. In my application there is a ribbon with several tabs (Office-like). Thus, not all controls are actually visible to the user, but they're still on the same form. I thought of building user controls, but I'd still need an object that mediates.